# Set Firefox as Emacs generic-browser

Tags: firefox, emacs

Setting Emacs generic browser to Firefox does not work if a Firefox instance is already open.
We get the following error message:
"*Close Firefox: A copy of Firefox is already open.*".

Here is how I'm setting the browser from within Emacs.

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
        engine/browser-function 'browse-url-generic
        ;; Chrome because Firefox will complain that a copy is already open.
        browse-url-generic-program "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome")
```

What Chrome does, essentially, is redirect the call to open a new instance into a call to open a new tab within the existing instance.

Is there any way to achieve the same with firefox?

Comment: Are you saying that the standard `browse-url-firefox` option doesn't work?

Comment: @phils thanks for the comment. Setting the `browse-url-browser-function` to `browse-url-firefox` and setting the `browse-url-firefox-program` to firefox's path raises the same error at my end. So no, it doesn't work.

Comment: This works for me on Windows, so this may be an OS-specific problem.

Comment: could be a firefox version issue to. I personally use the whatever browser is set as os's default browser

    (setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)